Which anisohedral polyomino has the fewest edges?
Below is an example of an anisohedral polyomino which has 10 edges. Are there anisohedral polyominos with fewer edges?


The following polyomino has only 8 edges:

A bit of background: My starting point for this investigation was Joseph Myers page: Polyform Tiling From this page, pictures of several anisohedral polyominoes are available for download. Looking at one of the diagrams for n=16, k=2: ( reproduced here with my annotation )

I removed the line separating two tiles, and added my own line splitting the resulting polyomino in two ( shown in red ). In this way, I was able to reduce the edge-count to 8, while keeping the tiling working as before.
I believe 8 is minimal. To go further, the only polyomino with 6 edges is an L-polyomino of some kind. L-polyominoes tile the plane thus would not satisfy the condition of being anisohedral.
